# Split PDF at page level, saving bookmark text as custom property

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to take a long pdf and split it at the page level.  The PDF is bookmarked in the style "Exhibit 1F, Page x of y)."  [image]

So the goal is each page is a new pdf with a custom property of the Exhibit and page marking from which it came in the original pdf.  I have struggling with this all day with the correct way to get the bookmark.  VCode will claim "GetOutlines" is depreciated, "use outline" instead.  When I do so, I get the following error:

```
    File "c:\Users\stand\venv\SelectandSplitTool.py", line 40, in <module>
    split_and_add_property(input_pdf_path, output_folder)
  File "c:\Users\stand\venv\SelectandSplitTool.py", line 13, in split_and_add_property
    bookmarks = pdf_reader.outline()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

If I try "_get_outline()" I get this error:

```
     File "c:\Users\stand\venv\SelectandSplitTool.py", line 40, in <module>
    split_and_add_property(input_pdf_path, output_folder)
  File "c:\Users\stand\venv\SelectandSplitTool.py", line 16, in split_and_add_property
    bookmark_text = bookmarks[page_num].title  # or bookmarks[page_num].get('/Page', '')
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'
```

Here is my code:

```
import PyPDF2
import os

def split_and_add_property(input_pdf_path, output_folder):
    with open(input_pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)

        for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
            pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
            pdf_writer.add_page(pdf_reader.pages[page_num])

            # Get the bookmark for the current page
            bookmarks = pdf_reader._get_outline()
            
            if page_num < len(bookmarks):
                bookmark_text = bookmarks[page_num].title  # or bookmarks[page_num].get('/Page', '')
                
                # Convert to string to avoid TypeError
                bookmark_text = str(bookmark_text)

                # Create a custom property for the bookmark text
                pdf_writer.add_metadata({
                    '/RecordLocation': bookmark_text
                })

                output_pdf_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"Page_{page_num + 1}.pdf")

                with open(output_pdf_path, 'wb') as output_file:
                    pdf_writer.write(output_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_pdf_path = r"C:\Users\stand\venv\Input_file.pdf"
    output_folder = r"C:\Users\stand\venv\output_folder"
    
    # Replace with the desired output folder path

    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    split_and_add_property(input_pdf_path, output_folder)
```